# Eclipse New Maven Project only shows archetypes from maven

Tags: maven, m2eclipse

While running maven from terminal, I get a list of around 2000 different archetypes belonging to various groups. But whenever I create a New Maven Project in Eclipse, I can only see a list of archeytpes from from group id **org.apache.maven.archetypes**

[image: Maven Snapshot]

How can I get a more comprehensive list consisting of other groups ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Double-check your `Windows -> Preferences -> Maven -> Archetypes.` preferences.

From [Import Maven Remote Archetype Catalogs in Eclipse](https://howtodoinjava.com/tools/eclipse/how-to-import-maven-remote-archetype-catalogs-in-eclipse/):

[image: https://howtodoinjava.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/Maven-archetype-option-in-eclipse.png]

Try for instance to import http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/archetype-catalog.xml.

Then a new maven project should list *all* archetypes available:

[image: https://howtodoinjava.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/Jersey-remote-archetypes.png]